# Extract and Resample Functions in R raster package: Area-Weighted Values

Tags: r, extract, r-raster

I made this post in [other forum](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/235175/raster-extract-function-area-weighted-values) as well, but since I really need a reply, i post it here once more.

I am working in R and want to calculate the value of a polygon derived from the intersecting cells of a raster. The value should consider the weights on each intersecting cell. When I try to run the "extract" function with a sample raster and polygon I get different weights that the ones I calculate manually, resulting in different final value.

Here is my sample code:

```
require(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=2, ncol=2, xmn=-180, xmx=60, ymn=-30, ymx=90)   
r[] <- c(1,2,4,5)    
s <- raster(xmn=-120, xmx=-40, ymn=20, ymx=60, nrow=1, ncol=1)    
s.pl <- as(s, 'SpatialPolygons')    
w <- raster::extract(r, s.pl, method="simple",weights=T, normalizeWeights=F)    
mean.value <- raster::extract(r, s.pl, method="simple",weights=T, fun=mean)
```

The value I get is 2.14 but according to the actual weights of the cells it should be 2. More specifically for every part of the polygon that intersects with different cell the data are:

```
 Area Value
 1800 1
  600 2
  600 4
  200 5
```

So the final value of the polygon based on the above should be 2.

Can it be because of the projection that is in lat/lon? But even when I assign projection in meters I have the same result. How can I get the value of 2 that I am interested in? I also tried with "resample" function but I get different results as well.

My final target is to create a new raster with different resolution and extents from the original one and assign the values based on the weights of the cells of the original raster that intersect with the cells of the new raster. But it seems that neither resample nor extract functions give the expected outcome.

Comment: What other forum? Please link to the question, if you must cross-post.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/235175/raster-extract-function-area-weighted-values

Comment: I suspect you're expecting something which `extract` is unable to deliver. If you read `?extract`, you will notice " If y represents polygons, the extract method returns the values of the cells of a Raster* object that are covered by a polygon. *A cell is covered if its center is inside the polygon* (but see the weights option for considering partly covered cells;". Perhaps you could coerce your raster to a polygon (`rasterToPolygons`) and find areas of overlap using `rgeos` package?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Roman, hvala lepa :) I read about the y polygons, but i though that with the weight option active is would give the desired result. Could you maybe me more specific with the rgeos package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume we have a raster `A` and two SpatialPolygon objects `[B, C]` that are not rectangular (hexagons in this case).
For demonstrating purposes the center of hexagon `B` is defined to be the center of our raster `A` (see left plot below). Hexagon `C` is shifted to the right along the horizontal axis.

```
require(raster)
require(scales)

A    <- raster(nrow=2, ncol=2, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-180, ymx=180)
A[]  <- c(1,2,4,5)    
A.pl <- as(A, 'SpatialPolygons')
B    <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(0, 100, 100, 0, -100, -100, 0), 
                                                         c(100, 50, -50, -100, -50, 50, 100)))), 'B')))
C    <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(40, 140, 140, 40, -60, -60, 40), 
                                                         c(100, 50, -50, -100, -50, 50, 100)))), 'C')))
```

### Object B

Since hexagon `B` is in the center, the weights should all equal 0.25.
We can easily derive from the plot that the area of the hexagons is 30000 (imagine a square that the hexagon fits in (40000) and substract 2 rectangulars (-10000), each consisting of 2 of the 4 corners you have to cut off). Therefore, each intersection area is of size 7500 and `7500/30000 = 0.25`

```
# get intersections
intsct.B <- raster::intersect(B, A.pl)
intsct.C <- raster::intersect(C, A.pl)

### B
area.B <- B@polygons[[1]]@area

weights <- unlist(lapply(intsct.B@polygons, function(x) {
  slot(x, 'area')/area.B
}))
weights
> [1] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
```

Now we get the value of the cells that each intersection polygon falls in and compute the mean.

```
vals    <- unlist(lapply(intsct.B@polygons, function(x) { 
  extract(A, data.frame(t(slot(x, 'labpt'))))
}))

sum(weights * vals)
> [1] 3
```

As we would expect, the mean of `c(1, 2, 4, 5)` is `3`.

[image: Hexagon B and its intersections with A]

### Object C

Now lets do the same with object `C`

```
### C
area.C <- C@polygons[[1]]@area

weights <- unlist(lapply(intsct.C@polygons, function(x) {
  slot(x, 'area')/area.C
}))
weights
> [1] 0.13 0.37 0.13 0.37

vals    <- unlist(lapply(intsct.C@polygons, function(x) { 
  extract(A, data.frame(t(slot(x, 'labpt'))))
}))

sum(weights * vals)
> [1] 3.24
```

Again, as we would expect the mean is bigger (since the weights for the cells with values 2 and 5 are higher). Also, since we shifted the hexagon along one axis only, it makes sense that 2 weights occur twice.

[image: Hexagon C and its intersections with A]

### Raster with higher number of cells

The next plot shows the intersections of `B` (left hand side) and `C` (rhs) with a `4x4` raster with values `c(1:8, 10:17)`. For `B` there are 12 intersections and for `C` 8. Notice again that the mean for `B` is exactly 9 because of the symmetry.

[image]

This should work for any `SpatialPolygons` object. Be sure to use the same CRS for the objects you throw into `intersect`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin. I have some questions, if you have more time. 1. Does it work with non-rectangular areas as well? or prod function will give wrong results? Also, I read something that intersect of raster package works fine for rectangular areas, but not for different shapes. 2. Can it be upgraded to work for rasterstacks and moreover when the new raster (s) has more than 1 cell? Thanks again :)

Comment: Made an edit. This should answer at least some of your questions. Go ahead and just do some trial and error...

Comment: Hi Martin, I was checking your reply for some new analysis I am doing and have one question that you could reply: The "area.C" is the total area of the polygon. What I noticed, is that the summation of the "weights" is not equal to 1, because the summation of the 'area' attribute is not equal to "area.C". For your example sum(weights)=1, but for my current analysis, there is about 0.03% difference. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Not sure. I am currently in the Alpes and spendm ore time in the snow than in front of my notebook. Will check it out when I am back home.

Comment: Enjoy your time and thanks so much for all your help with this question I have, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I managed to do based on the replies of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140504/extracting-intersection-areas-in-r) post.

```
require(raster)
require(rgeos)
r <- raster(nrow=2, ncol=2, xmn=-180, xmx=60, ymn=-30, ymx=90)    
r[] <- c(1,2,4,5)    
r <- stack(r, r*2, r^2)
s <- raster(xmn=-120, xmx=-40, ymn=20, ymx=60, nrow=1, ncol=1)    
s.pl <- as(s, 'SpatialPolygons')    
r.s <- as(r, 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame')
pi1 <- gIntersection(r.s, s.pl, byid = T)
areas1 <- data.frame(area=sapply(pi1@polygons, FUN=function(x) {slot(x, 'area')}))
row.names(areas1) <- sapply(pi1@polygons, FUN=function(x) {slot(x, 'ID')})
areas1$Pol.old <- as.numeric(vapply(strsplit(rownames(areas1), " "), `[`, 1, FUN.VALUE=character(1)))
areas1$pol.new <- as.numeric(vapply(strsplit(rownames(areas1), " "), `[`, 2, FUN.VALUE=character(1)))
f <- r.s@data
seqs <- match(areas1$Pol.old, rownames(f))
ar <- cbind(areas1, f[seqs,])
ar[,-(1:3)] <- ar[,-(1:3)]*ar$area
f <- aggregate.data.frame(ar, by=list(ar$pol.new), FUN=sum)
f[,-(1:4)] <- f[,-(1:4)]/f$area  
ar.v <- as.matrix(f[, -c(1:4)])
s2 <- stack(s)
s1 <- setValues(s2, ar.v)
```

If somebody can suggest nicer and/or faster code, please let me know, cause I don't like my approach very much.